# XPATH to select NEAREST preceding node

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

How can I select the nearest preceding node called BName that DOES NOT have a parent called "Test" in Xpath 2.0?

Expression I'm thinking of is something like:

```
preceding::BName[1](not[@parent::Test])
```

Comment: please post a sample of the xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
preceding::BName[not(parent::Test)][1]
```

#### Explanation

```
preceding::BName
```

selects all preceding nodes with name `BName` in reverse document order.

```
preceding::BName[not(parent::Test)]
```

only keeps the nodes which don't have a parent with name `Test`, i.e. removes all nodes with a `Test` parent.

```
preceding::BName[not(parent::Test)][1]
```

selects the first node. Since the node set is in reverse document order, this is the node nearest to the context node.

#### Example

Given the document

```
<Document>
    <Container>
        <BName id="1"/>
    </Container>
    <Container>
        <BName id="2"/>
    </Container>
    <Test>
        <BName id="3"/>
        <Context/>
    </Test>
</Document>
```

the expression

```
//Context/preceding::BName[not(parent::Test)][1]
```

selects the node

```
<BName id="2"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly. What about instead of a Parent node, I'm trying to avoid nodes with GRANDPARENT nodes = Test? [I'll ask a new question in SO]